# How to prevent code repetition in while loop for chunked data processing?

Tags: java

I'm reading a file, collected the processed lines, and after each chunk of collection write them in batches (eg to a file or a database).

When the loop terminates (= file is read completely), I then have to call the writer one more time. Otherwise I would not catch the last chunk.

Question: can I improve the code somehow to prevent the repetition of an additional write() call?

```
List<String> collect = new ArrayList<>();

String line;
while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
    String processed = processline(line);
    collect.add(processed);

    //write each x chunks to file
    if (collect.size() % 1000 == 0) {
        writer.write(collect);
        collect = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

//can I prevent repetition here?
if (!collect.isEmpty()) {
    writer.write(collect);
}
```

Comment: Could you add the if statement you have afterwards condition `!collect.isEmpty()` to your while loop as an or `||`?

Answer (score 5):

Encapsulate the buffering logic (because that's what you're doing, buffering) in a separate class. But you'll always have to write when the buffer is too big *and* when you're done reading.

```
class BufferingWriter implements Closeable {
    private List<String> buffer = new ArrayList<>(1000);
    private MyWriter writer;

    public void write(String line) {
        buffer.add(line);
        if (buffer.size() >= 1000) {
            flush();
        }
    }

    public void flush() {
        writer.write(buffer);
        buffer.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        flush();
        // TBD: Pass the close call onto MyWriter if that is possible
        // or otherwise flag this writer as closed
    }
}
```

```
List<String> collect = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferingWriter bwriter = new BufferingWriter(writer)) {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
        String processed = processline(line);
        bwriter.write(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to make it Closeable (enabling use of try-with-resources instead of having to remember to call flush at the end) and initialize the ArrayList with an initial capacity of 1000 to avoid re-allocations.

Comment: I like it. @KlitosKyriacou 's suggestions sound good to me too.

Comment: I think this will also be doing the same thing but in a more proper way, you are calling flush at the end and the OP is calling if block.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my suggestion:

```
    List<String> collect = new ArrayList<>();

    String line = reader.read();
    String nextLine;

    while (line != null) {

        nextLine = reader.read();

        String processed = processline(line);
        collect.add(processed);

        //write each x chunks to file
        if (collect.size() % 1000 == 0 || nextLine == null) {
            writer.write(collect);
            collect = new ArrayList<>();
            line = nextLine;
            continue;
        }

        line = nextLine;     

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a do-while loop?

```
List<String> collect = new ArrayList<>();

String line;
do {
   line = reader.read();
   if(line != null) {
      String processed = processline(line);
      collect.add(processed);
   }

   if (collect.size() % 1000 == 0 
       || (line == null && !collect.isEmpty())) { // end of file
      writer.write(collect);
      collect = new ArrayList<>();
   } 

} while(line != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this? Not sure this is an improvement...

```
List<String> collect = new ArrayList<>();

for (;;) {
    String line = reader.read();
    boolean done = line == null;
    if (!done) {
        String processed = processline(line);
        collect.add(processed);
    }

    //write each x chunks to file
    if ((collect.size() % 1000 == 0) || done) {
        if (!collect.isEmpty()) {
            writer.write(collect);
        }
        if (done) {
            break;
        }
        collect = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally think `while (true) {` is more idiomatic than `for (;;)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this but still you will have one extra line to get the last chunk.

```
List<String> collect = new ArrayList<>();

String line;
do {
   line = reader.read();
   if(line != null) {
        String processed = processline(line);
        collect.add(processed);

       //write each x chunks to file
       if (collect.size() % 1000 == 0) {
            writer.write(collect);
            collect = new ArrayList<>();
       }
   }else{
       writer.write(collect);
   }
} while(line != null);
```